# Concatenate objects in an array to a SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to set the segments of a svg path dynamically. I store the segments as objects in an array. But I am having problems to concatenate them to a valid path with a space as separator. I tried join() but I am not sure how to access the objects in the array correctly. What is the best way to achieve this?

`d="M 10 20 L 10 0 L 30 50 z"`

```
let segments = [
       {
           "type": "M",
           "values": [ 10, 20 ]
       },
       {
            "type": "L",
            "values": [ 10, 0 ]
       },
       {
             "type": "L",
             "values": [ 30, 5 ]
       }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map + join should do fine here:

```
> segments.map(seg => `${seg.type} ${seg.values.join(' ')}`).join(' ') + " z";
  "M 10 20 L 10 0 L 30 5 z"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```js
let segments = [
    {
        "type": "M",
        "values": [ 10, 20 ]
    },
    {
        "type": "L",
        "values": [ 10, 0 ]
    },
    {
        "type": "L",
        "values": [ 30, 5 ]
    }
];

function getSvgPath(data) {
  return data.reduce((acc, val) => {    
    const item = `${val.type} ${val.values.join(' ')}`;
    acc.push(item);
    return acc;
  }, []).join(' ');
}

const path = getSvgPath(segments);
console.log(path);
```

Comment: This is using `reduce` to emulate `map` :)

Comment: That's true! :)